# Oracle SQL - remove duplicates from listagg

Tags: sql, oracle

The following script gives me a one line table, showing 'manuf_skus' and 'distr_skus' in one row (using the 'listagg' function)...

```
select 
pd.part_no, 
pd.catnr, 
pd.prodtyp, 
pd.packtyp, 
pd.description, 
ip.purchase_type,
li.cust_catnr categroy,
li.licence_expire,
listagg (nrb.p_catnr, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY nrb.p_catnr) manuf_skus,
listagg (st.selection_no, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY st.selection_no) distr_skus,
nvl(pd.fod_idc, 'N') FOD_IDC, 
(select max(acp.qty_free_idc)    
    from oes_fod_match acp 
    where pd.part_no = acp.part_no 
    and acp.type = 'SUP' 
    and acp.cre_dat = (select max(acp1.cre_dat) 
                        from oes_fod_match acp1 
                        where acp.part_no = acp1.part_no 
                        and acp1.qty_free > 0 
                        and acp1.type = 'SUP')) qty_free_idc, 
(select nvl(sum(pl.qty_onhand), 0) 
    from part_loc pl 
    where pl.part_no = pd.part_no 
    and pl.location_type = 'IN') total_stock_comp,
(select nvl(max(pp.qty), 0) 
    from oes_purpos pp 
    where pp.av_part_no = pd.part_no 
    and pp.c_status != 'D' 
    and pp.datneu = (select max(pp1.datneu) 
                        from oes_purpos pp1 
                        where pp1.av_part_no = pp.av_part_no 
                        and pp1.c_status != 'D')) last_aw_po_qty,
(select nvl(sum(ps.requ_qty - nvl(ps.del_qty, 0)), 0) 
    from oes_purpos pp, 
    oes_purseg ps 
    where ps.headnr = pp.headnr 
    and ps.posnr = pp.posnr 
    and pp.av_part_no = pd.part_no 
    and ps.c_status not in ('9', 'D') 
    and ps.o_status not in ('D', '9')) open_aw_po_qty,
(select sum(al.qty_required) 
    from allocations al 
    where pd.part_no = al.component_part 
    and al.status_code between '4' and '8') comp_alloc
FROM part_description pd 
INNER JOIN inventory_purchase ip 
   ON ip.part_no = pd.part_no 
INNER JOIN scm_prodtyp pt 
   ON pt.prodtyp = pd.prodtyp 
INNER JOIN oes_fod_match acp 
   ON acp.part_no = pd.part_no
INNER JOIN leos_item li
   ON pd.part_no = li.av_part_no
INNER JOIN inventory_purchase ip 
   ON ip.part_no = pd.part_no 
INNER JOIN scm_prodtyp pt 
   ON pt.prodtyp = pd.prodtyp 
INNER JOIN oes_fod_match acp 
   ON acp.part_no = pd.part_no 
INNER JOIN part_description pd3 
   ON pd3.part_no = pd.part_no 
INNER JOIN NCF_COMPPART ncf 
   ON ncf.item_part_no = pd.part_no 
INNER JOIN oes_nrbom nrb 
   ON ncf.catnr = nrb.c_catnr 
  AND ncf.prodtyp = nrb.c_prodtyp 
  AND ncf.packtyp = nrb.c_packtyp 
  AND ncf.vernr = nrb.c_vernr
INNER JOIN part_description pd2
   ON nrb.p_catnr = pd2.catnr
  AND nrb.p_prodtyp = pd2.prodtyp
  AND nrb.p_packtyp = pd2.packtyp
LEFT OUTER JOIN BDS_SELECTION_ORG@sid_to_cdsuk st
   ON 9||nrb.p_catnr = st.selection_no
WHERE pd.cunr in ('649830', 'W30000') 
   and pd.catnr = '2EDVD0017'
   and pd.fod_idc = 'Y' 
   and pt.prodgrp = 'AW'
GROUP BY
   pd.part_no, 
   pd.catnr, 
   pd.prodtyp, 
   pd.packtyp, 
   pd.description,
   ip.purchase_type,
   li.cust_catnr,
   li.licence_expire, 
   pd.fod_idc
```

What I would like to add is the following subquery ...

```
(select sum(ds.planqty - nvl(ds.delqty, 0)) 
    from oes_opos op, 
    oes_oposdelseg ds
    where ds.ordnr = op.ordnr 
    and ds.posnr = op.posnr
    and op.catnr = nrb.p_catnr 
    and op.prodtyp = nrb.p_prodtyp 
    and op.packtyp = nrb.p_packtyp
    and ds.c_status not in ('9', 'D') 
    and op.ol_typ = 'XX'
    group by
    pd.catnr, nrb.catnr, nrb.prodtyp, nrb.packtyp) open_manuf_qty
```

... to make this work I have to add the following GROUP BY's

```
nrb.p_catnr,
nrb.p_prodtyp,
nrb.p_packtyp
```

But, when I add this subquery, the 'manuf_skus' and 'distr_skus' are no longer in one row. I assume this is because I've had to add the extra group by's. Is there of adding this sum subquery and still keeping one row?

Thanks
All

Answer (score 0):

Are the additional rows duplicates?  If so, you might try adding a distinct:

```
select distinct 
pd.part_no, 
pd.catnr, 
pd.prodtyp,
```

....

Comment: Yes additional rows are duplicates apart from columns 'MANUF_SKUS, and 'DISTR_SKUS' ... I tried DISTINCT but, unfortunately I get the same 'duplicate' rows.